# Phone Video + 3D tracking spatial data for compositing?

Tags: 3d, tracking, compositing, metadata

With all of the AR capabilities of actual phones, I wonder if there is any app to record video with all the spatial data of the camera which lets you export the virtual 3D camera directly from the shot to be used for compositing.

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of is [CV-AR from cineversity](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cv-ar/id1378696551), which uses apple AR kit to capture facial animation, and works in conjunction with Maxon Cinema 4D.  I don't think depth sensing on phones is quite to the point where anything further than a selfie is very accurate, although I'm sure that'll change in the very near term if it hasn't already.

Comment: That looks interesting! Does it work with C4D-lite with After Effects?

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer as I've found a better method:

[CamTrackAR](https://fxhome.com/product/camtrackar) is excellent.  The paid version can generate camera tracks for After Effects and Blender.  Couple it with [HDReye](https://hdreye.app/) to make an HDRI.exr world "dome" and you can get some very convincing compositing using Blender and AE.